# Filter children based on search term

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I've been trying to figure out how to model my data in ElasticSearch to accomplish filtering nested objects based on a search.

Here is my existing data mode:

```
[
   {
      "job":{
         "jobId":"d2f462c1-3015-460e-aa4f-3e5ed8969b4a",
         "jobName":"2651",
         "otherStuff":"my stuff",
         "order":[
            {
               "description":"D-Style, To Match",
               "orderID":"ad86b512-6da3-407d-931d-d20e8717650f",
               "poNumber":"2651-1"
            },
            {
               "description":"Switch-Style, To Match",
               "orderID":"3d86b512-6da3-407d-931d-d20e8717650f",
               "poNumber":"some data"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is:

1. If I do a search and it matches any value in that "job object" (including nested objects) then return the top level job information every time.
2. At the same time, if that data matches only 1 nested "order" object return only that one order.

So if I searched on "some data" I'd expect to see this returned in the result set:

```
[
   {
      "job":{
         "jobId":"d2f462c1-3015-460e-aa4f-3e5ed8969b4a",
         "jobName":"2651",
         "otherStuff":"my stuff",
         "order":[
            {
               "description":"Switch-Style, To Match",
               "orderID":"3d86b512-6da3-407d-931d-d20e8717650f",
               "poNumber":"some data"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

I've researched Nested object type and also Parent/Child relationships. I can't to figure out how to accomplish this with only 1 query. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does it help to turn the query on its head and try searching at the top level (order) then filter with has_parent to find a job that matches? Trying to get my head around how you get just the one nested result you want.

Comment: @Paul I have a very similar problem.  Did you ever find a solution to this?